# dask sort index after load from dataframe with index non-sorted

Tags: dask

I have created dataframe with non-sorted index with pandas and save it to parquet. Later, if I load with dask, How do I perform sort index? Do I have to do something like,
`pdf.reset_index().set_index(idx)`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the answer is yes, your approach is correct. For example, searching for `"sort_index"` in Dask issues does not really yield [any relevant results](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues?q=%22sort_index%22).

Keep in mind that sorting out-of-core is quite a difficult operation. It's possible you might get more stable results (or even better performance) in Pandas if your dataset fits in your memory.